# Same Color Differs in Appearance Between Windows 7 and Windows 10

Tags: wpf, colors, windows-8, windows-7, windows-10

Bear in mind, that this is the **exact** same source code (theme, xaml, solution, everything) in the **exact** same version of Blend 2015. The only difference is that one screenshot is from Windows 10, and the other is from Windows 7.

Windows 10:
[image: Windows 10]

Windows 7

[image: Windows 7]

FWIW, the same effect can be seen at runtime in the app. (Windows 8 renders the same as Windows 10.) I'm dumbfounded on why this is occurring.

Why is this occurring? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage review of the video driver... check the video adapter vendor site to ensure you've the current version and if so... inquire with them why the render colour request isn't being upheld.

Comment: Interesting that you would mention that. Truth be told, the Windows 7 image is from a VM hosted in VMware Workstation Player, and have been able to replicate the issue in VirtualBox, but I have never tried on bare metal. I'm not even sure where I could find a bare metal machine to run Windows 7 on. Let alone for free.

Comment: I spooled up another VM this time on Azure, and I was able to replicate the same discoloration issue, so I would hesitate to blame it on graphics drivers. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: If you take the same driver and execute it on a different VM service... I'd not expect much change either.

Comment: I'd encourage a visit to the driver vendor site to see if the version you have installed on your VM is current (read:  often bugs are discovered and resolved, but not promoted very well)... if that didn't remedy the issue... drop a note to the driver vendor... the odds are, you're not alone experiencing this.  
As for getting hardware to run Windows 7... you may consider creating a USB bootable stick.